# Command options for an Exe

Tags: c#, .net, command-line

I have a console application written in C sharp(.net) which takes some command line arguments from the the command prompt.
Now based on the option given to the application It will perform some action.
like bellow.

```
> TestExe.exe Option1 (it will perform action1)
> TestExe.exe Option2 (it will perform action2)
> TestExe.exe Option3 (it will perform action3)
```

Now What I want is when user will type the application name and press tab than user should get  all the options. This will make the application user friendly rather than remembering the options.

Can any one give me some direction..?

Comment: For what platform? There is nothing  cross-platform to do this.

Comment: Have you tried *anything*?

Comment: @DarkFalcon this is windows platform and I am using .net framework 4.0.

Comment: I understand that you want to get all the possible options of an executable inside the commandline or the powershell on windows? This is not possible, because it is the bahavior of the system and not of your application. But you can add a commandline option like "?" or "help" which could printout all your possible options. This is the common way to do such things.

Comment: @Crono I am finding any direction that's why posted the question.Can u help me out?

Comment: @vandango no he said it's his own console application.

Comment: @Arijit basically you want a popup window appearing right below where the user is typing. Correct?

Comment: @vandango I already did that.. and its working in the production. But I want the options to come the moment user will type the AppName and press tab, something like when we press "cd" and press tab we can see the all the directories and rotate over the list.

Comment: Make the program provide it's own command-line and implement in there what you need.

Comment: @Crono please refer the previous comment for clarification.

Comment: @alk can you please explain what you told with some code snippets?????

Answer (score 2):

What you're asking for isn't possible.

Instead, have four executables, one of which is the program you're describing above. Then, you have three others, each one representing one of the three options (three batch files would also work, and probably be a bit easier to create/maintain). These other three simply execute the first with the appropriate option.

Now, since you have four real files, command completion using tab will work - except instead of completing a parameter (which again, is not possible), the shell will be completing the command itself (a real file).

Comment: Actually I will have more number of options not 3 or 4. And its not a good idea to segregate the codebase in different console apps. That will add lot of complication.But Thanks for the option. I will check the feasibility.

Comment: How is it not possible? The console app is his, he can make anything he want appears on it.

Comment: @Chrono Can Windows or Linux provide completion of parameters that are specific to an executable?

Answer (score 0):

I think the common straight-forward solution is to add a support to '?' and 'help' parameter, so when the user doesn't know which parameter he should provide for the desired action, he just types TestExe.exe /? or TestExe.exe /help and gets the list.
A good practice will be also to show the same legend in case the user runs the program without parameters at all.

Answer (score 0):

You could make a PowerShell wrapper for your exe that will more or less do what you want.

```
[CmdletBinding()]
param(
    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('Option1','Option2','Option3')]
    [string]$Option
)

TestExe.exe $Option
```

If you saved that script as `TestScript.ps1`, then at the PowerShell prompt you could type `TestScript -Option`, then you could press tab to go through the three options.

(You could rename `Option` in the script to whatever you want of course.)